# Excel Macro copy paste with conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in excel which works but not perfect as I want it.Couldn't find solution and need your ideas.

Here what it does:  Copy from Settings paste values to the first non empty cell in calculation sheet.It does ok

Here is the my code for this:

```
Sub support()
Sheets("Settings").Select
Range("S411:S421").Select
Selection..Copy
Sheets("Calculation").Select
Range("C4").Select
Range("C4").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

But what I want to copy only non empty cells and values which are not 0 to the calculation page between those 10 rows. (so I should skip copying 0 and empty cells) Any easy trick that you can direct me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `AutoFilter()`

```
Sub support()
    With Sheets("Settings").Range("S410:S421") '<--| reference wanted range and the cell above it as the "header"
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(1, 1)) Then .Cells(1, 1).Value = "dummyheader" '<--| add a "dummy" header value if it's empty
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>0" '<--| filter referenced range with "not empty" and "not zero" values
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            Sheets("Calculation").Range("C4").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "dummyheader" Then .Cells(1, 1).ClearContents '<--| remove "dummy" header, if there
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: wowwww this is great idea and works perfect.  I am angry to myself, I didn't thought autofilter :(

Comment: just adding that if you know for sure that S410 cell is _always_ not empty then you can omit both `If IsEmpty(.Cells(1, 1)) Then .Cells(1, 1).Value = "dummyheader"` and `If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "dummyheader" Then .Cells(1, 1).ClearContents` statements

Comment: thank you most probably is not going to be empty but can't be sure.I will see over time and keep this in mind thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Would You like to copy from `Range("S411:S421")` to `Range("C4")..->` everytime? Or these ranges can be changed?

TRY:

```
    Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
j = 4
For i = 411 To 421

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(i, 19) <> 0 And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(i, 19) <> "" Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(i, 19).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculation").Cells(j, 3).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
j = j + 1
End If


Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: yes i want to copy everytime same cells and ranges are not changing.  but the row changing at the place where I past it.

Comment: Range("S411:S421") where I copy contains formulas so for that reason there are different values each time.

Comment: Yes, when you have for example(10,0,-,0,-,45,78,96,0,-,121) in Range S411:S421, you want to have (10,45,78,96,121) in C4 and down, yop?